# Why VMWARE is asking me to select the OS when there is an OS in the Iso?

Tags: vmware, operating-systems, iso-image

I am using Vmware and I downloaded a Kali Linux Iso. This means that a linux OS is inside the ISO, right? If that's the case why do I need to choose a OS when creating a Virtual Machine in Vmware?

I want to understand what is happening. Does Vmware provide the OS and the ISO only the file system? How does that work?

[Vmware asking me to choose an OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9B4L.png)

Comment: Old OSes don't support new (virtual) hardware and new OSes don't support old hardware. That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

VMware wants to know both:

(1) What OS type are you installing (Windows, Linux - what flavor of Linux). It needs this for the install, driver and hardware selection and for the VMware Tools it will need.

It will do this as modern VMware guest installations also install Tools as part of the total. This is a distinct advantage and was not always so with VMware and VBOX still needs extensions installed after. Tools will be in OS groups that accommodate numerous specific guests.

Automation of this task may come at some point, but currently there are thousands (and more thousands) of combinations of host hardware and guest operating systems.

Right now it is just easier to group things and asking the OS category is one of those groupings.

(2) Once it knows (1) it needs to know the location of the specific ISO file.

Seems to me here - Situation Normal.

Posted from my Kali VM within VMware Workstation Pro V16.

Comment: Ok. I don't quite get why Vmware would need to know the OS if the ISO already has an OS inside? ... The location seems logical.

Comment: Because there are so many Guest types, it needs to know (as I mentioned) for specific setup and tools. It seems easiest (to me) to do it that way. Remember VMware now does a complete install including tools so this is a good thing.

Comment: it could also be that VMware has always asked for OS type (back to VMware V1) and they just have not changed but may do some day.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so a a hypervisor, VMWare needs to present virtual hardware to the guest OS, configured in a way that is expected to work for that OS, and to configure the interaction between hypervisor itself and the host. Additionally not all virtualization features are available for all combinations of host and guest. Indicating which OS you are using also helps VMWare determine what guest tools installers will be used based on the available guest's capabilities (.exe, dpkg, rpm, etc).

VMWare doesn't supply any elements of the OS, other than the guest tools packages, which you optionally add after the OS is installed, so you still need the OS disk and it performs all the software install.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Workstation, Player, and Fusion can automatically detect *some* ISO images.  However, there is no standard way to identify the OS and version from an ISO image, so VMware needs custom logic to identify each one.  They're able to do that for some of the installation images from popular OSes, but there are far too many OSes to be able to automatically detect all of them.  Kali Linux is not one of the ones that can be automatically detected.

If you want to know why VMware software want to know the guest OS in the first place:

- Once upon a time in the days of binary translation, some guest OSes needed special, OS-specific performance tweaks.
- The UI uses the guest OS type to pick reasonable defaults based on the known recommended hardware configuration for the OS (e.g. the recommended about of RAM, recommended amount of disk, what NICs the OS includes drivers for, etc.).
- The UI uses the guest OS type to know whether VMware Tools are available for the guest OS and to mount the correct Tools installation image.
- In some cases, the UI might use the guest OS type to determine whether certain OS integration features should be enabled (although usually that should be determined by what capabilities VMware Tools report).

Answer (score 0):

VMware needs to ask an operating system because it needs to search for VMware tools for correct os if you don't select the correct operating system it will try to install the wrong VMware tools , and VMWare could auto-detect os maybe it could not detect which os is in the ISO